# Wordpress - no such file or directory issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting this error when I load up my Wordpress site:

> Warning:
>   include_once(../../plugins/acf-location-field-master/acf-location.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\cmpmushrooms.tld\wp-content\themes\shrooms_v0.1\functions.php
>   on line 455

The code it is referring to is this:

```
function my_register_fields()
{
    include_once('../../plugins/acf-location-field-master/acf-location.php');
}
```

I realise it is saying it cannot find the file but why is that? because it exists in the directory.

Comment: Are you sure it exists where you think it does?

Comment: Right now, this is the file you are asking to include `C:\wamp\www\cmpmushrooms.tld\wp-content\plugins\acf-location-field-master\acf-location.php`

Comment: can you please give the whole path in `include_once` and then check, if it works.

Comment: Why not `include_once ( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . /acf-location-field-master/acf-location.php');`?

Comment: @cpilko , that worked so if you want to make answer I Will accept

Comment: @Javacadabra Please let me know if my answer helped you solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should do this way to include file from WP plugins directory :

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'plugin-name/file-name.php');
```

If you want to include all files within that directory, use it like this:

```
foreach ( glob( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."plugin-name/*.php" ) as $file )
    include_once $file;
```

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
include_once ( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/acf-location-field-master/acf-location.php');
```